# MessageBox.Show()

Tags: .net, winforms

I would like to Show my Messagebox in the center of its parent form. if i move the form and show the messagebox, it always show in the center of the desktop. i want it to appear along with the form. 
Can you give me some tricks and advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Winforms-How can I make MessageBox appear centered on MainForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576156/winforms-how-can-i-make-messagebox-appear-centered-on-mainform)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use Window Hooks and center the message box yourself. There is a perfect article which shows this usage.

You can find it here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/CenterDialog.aspx

You can also use the class in your application without diving in too deep to find out how it actually works.

Comment: Article is great. Just need to understand it before applying it to my app. tnx. is there much easier way? heh..

Comment: The easiest way would be make a new MessageBox form yourself. That will be according to your taste and will look like the way you want it to be. Also, you can add any functionality you like.

Answer (score 2):

I made this class based on a class for Windows Forms which I found somwehere else.

Just add the class to your WPF project and provide "this" as a parameter to the helper method like this:

```
  MessageBoxHelper.PrepToCenterMessageBoxOnForm(this)"
```

Then show the message box:

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello there!");


/// <summary>
/// This class makes it possible to center a MessageBox over the parent dialog.
/// Usage example:
///         MessageBoxHelper.PrepToCenterMessageBoxOnForm(this);
///         MessageBox.Show("Hello there!);
/// </summary>
public static class MessageBoxHelper
{
    public static void PrepToCenterMessageBoxOnForm(Window window)
    {
        MessageBoxCenterHelper helper = new MessageBoxCenterHelper();
        helper.Prep(window);
    }

    private class MessageBoxCenterHelper
    {
        private int messageHook;
        private IntPtr parentFormHandle;

        public void Prep(Window window)
        {
            NativeMethods.CenterMessageCallBackDelegate callBackDelegate = new NativeMethods.CenterMessageCallBackDelegate(CenterMessageCallBack);
            GCHandle.Alloc(callBackDelegate);
            parentFormHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
            messageHook = NativeMethods.SetWindowsHookEx(5, callBackDelegate, new IntPtr(NativeMethods.GetWindowLong(parentFormHandle, -6)), NativeMethods.GetCurrentThreadId()).ToInt32();
        }

        private int CenterMessageCallBack(int message, int wParam, int lParam)
        {
            NativeMethods.RECT formRect;
            NativeMethods.RECT messageBoxRect;
            int xPos;
            int yPos;

            if (message == 5)
            {
                NativeMethods.GetWindowRect(parentFormHandle, out formRect);
                NativeMethods.GetWindowRect(new IntPtr(wParam), out messageBoxRect);

                xPos = (int)((formRect.Left + (formRect.Right - formRect.Left) / 2) - ((messageBoxRect.Right - messageBoxRect.Left) / 2));
                yPos = (int)((formRect.Top + (formRect.Bottom - formRect.Top) / 2) - ((messageBoxRect.Bottom - messageBoxRect.Top) / 2));

                NativeMethods.SetWindowPos(wParam, 0, xPos, yPos, 0, 0, 0x1 | 0x4 | 0x10);
                NativeMethods.UnhookWindowsHookEx(messageHook);
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }

    private static class NativeMethods
    {
        internal struct RECT
        {
            public int Left;
            public int Top;
            public int Right;
            public int Bottom;
        }

        internal delegate int CenterMessageCallBackDelegate(int message, int wParam, int lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(int hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        internal static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int hook, CenterMessageCallBackDelegate callback, IntPtr hMod, int dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool SetWindowPos(int hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, int uFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to say *where* you stole this code from. Attribution is important here. A Google search turns up a couple of possible sources: http://www.jasoncarr.com/technology/centering-a-message-box-on-the-active-window-in-csharp, http://code.google.com/p/lioneditor/source/browse/branches/imageEditorv2/FFTPatcher/PatcherLib/MyMessageBox.cs?spec=svn468&r=468.

Comment: Good idea. But please mind your words : "stole" that is a harsh expression. I explictly said "found somwhere else", but you are absolutely right about attribution.

Comment: And no, the original code did not come frome the link you added. It came from Jason Carr: http://www.jasoncarr.com/technology/centering-a-message-box-on-the-active-window-in-csharp. I just modified it to work in WPF.  Thanks Jason.

Comment: Ups. Didn't see you added that link :-)

Comment: You should create a variable to store the result of GCHandle.Alloc and call GCHandle.Free() inside of the Callback Hook after UnhookWindowsHookEx

Answer (score 1):

Set the owner of the message box window to your window (using the first parameter of `.Show()`), instead of not setting an owner.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cked7698.aspx) for a reference.

Comment: can you give me some example?
i've tried this:

IWin32Window win = this; 
MessageBox.Show(win,"TESTING");

Although, same result. Messagebox still pop up in the middle of the desktop

Comment: I suppose that depends on what `this` is. I'm afraid that my experience is limited to the native Win32 `MessageBox()` function, which is a bit different, and I got halfway through answering before I realised you were using WinForms. So I modified my answer to fit what I found in the reference, but I may still have some details missing. :)

Comment: Passing a window handle to MessageBox does not display the message box in the center of the parent. It is just to enable minimize/maximize with the parent and there is no specific task icon for the message box window.

Comment: can you give me an example to display messagebox in the center of the parent?

Comment: @Yogesh: interesting, perhaps the WinForms MessageBox isn't implemented using the Win32 MessageBox function.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before in C#. Here's what I remember.

Define a class:

```
public class IWindowWrapper : System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window
{
    public IWindowWrapper(IntPtr handle)
    {
        this.Handle= handle;
    }

    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get; 
        set;
    }
}
```

Define a class based on MessageBox.
Create a class based on MessageBox and create a new Show method :

```
public string Show(IWin32Window owner)
{
   if(owner == null)
   {
    this.ShowDialog();
   }
   else
   {
      //parentWindow.
      this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
      this.ShowDialog(owner);
   }

}
```

In your calling code (here it is assumed to be a winform and msgBox is based on the new message box class) call the new Show method and pass an IWindowWrapper instance on Show e.g.

```
msgBox.Show(new IWindowWrapper(this.Handle))
```

Comment: When you say "based", do you mean inherit? Im kinda new in C#. :)

Comment: Yes e.g. public class MyMessageBox : MessageBox ... etc.

Comment: You don't have to use C# to do this, but that's what I used. Is that the language that you're programming in?

Comment: The Second Code. Am i going to Inherit a Messagebox? or just create a form with the same style as Messagebox? this.ShowDialog() is not availabe if i inherit a messagebox

Comment: I'm using C#. i think this is not possible for me. anyone?

Comment: @ChrisBD: How do you plan to inherit a MessageBox? Can you show an example?

Comment: This absolutely DOES NOT WORK. You cannot inherit from MessageBox.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a very easy to use solution, and it works perfectly:**

- [Center MessageBox in Parent Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732443/center-messagebox-in-parent-form/3498791#3498791)

Steps:

1. Copy and paste that class into your project.  I used it without any editing.
2. To use the modified MessageBox, use this line of code in your project:

*(inside a `UserControl` or a `Form`)*

```
MessageBoxEx.Show(this, "Please fix the validation errors before saving.", "Validation Errors");
```