# center MessageBox in parent form

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, messagebox

Is there a easy way to center MessageBox in parent form in .net 2.0

Comment: This question cannot be a duplicate of the linked question, because this was asked a year earlier.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From a comment on [Joel Spolsky's blog](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.524811.3):

> A Messagebox is always centered on the screen. You can provide an owner, but that is just for Z-order, not centering. The only way is to use Win32 hooks and center it yourself. You can find code doing that online if you search for it.
>
> Much easier is to just write your own message box class and add centering functionality. Then you can also add default captioning, Do not show again-checkbox and making them modeless.

"Win32 hooks" probably refers to using `SetWindowsHookEx` as shown in [this example](http://vbnet.mvps.org/code/hooks/messageboxhookcentre.htm).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just wonder why Microsoft left this out, leaving us to write a custom class to achieve a small functionality.

Comment: @Ramji, I dont think Microsoft left it out, they have the best UI designers hired, they certainly make things more useful, in case of alert, you dont want to be looking around corners of your monitor to judge what happened, it is centered so that it can be spotted easily.

Comment: @Akash - I think in this case, I'd have to disagree with the 'best' UI designers. If i'm looking at a window that's not centered, say on the top of the screen, it would be distracting to have all my alerts pop up below my center of focus. Hence why there is a need for this workaround to center alerts to the center of the user's focus rather than a generalised focus to the center of the screen.

Comment: @Joe agreed especially now that we have multiple monitors.

Comment: Good news is, Task Dialogs natively support this feature (but they're not trivial to use with P/Invoke), with the flag `TDF_POSITION_RELATIVE_TO_WINDOW`.

Comment: I know this a old thread, but i have to say that in todays world, with big monitors with multiple times the resolution of a few years ago, center on screen its not the best idea. It made sense when monitors were small and everyone would maximize windows, but now... No, it should be parent center.

Comment: In my two-monitor setup, the app is running on the right screen and the message box is perfectly centered in the left screen.

Comment: Given this,has anyone thought of just creating a simple class / form within the application for the messagebox? It seems this is the root cause, that the messagebox is not actually part of the application.

Answer (score 94):

I really needed this in C# and found [Center MessageBox C#](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/267125-center-messagebox-c).

Here's a nicely formatted version

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;   

public class MessageBoxEx
{
    private static IWin32Window _owner;
    private static HookProc _hookProc;
    private static IntPtr _hHook;

    public static DialogResult Show(string text)
    {
        Initialize();
        return MessageBox.Show(text);
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(string text, string caption)
    {
        Initialize();
        return MessageBox.Show(text, caption);
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(string text, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons)
    {
        Initialize();
        return MessageBox.Show(text, caption, buttons);
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(string text, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon)
    {
        Initialize();
        return MessageBox.Show(text, caption, buttons, icon);
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(string text, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defButton)
    {
        Initialize();
        return MessageBox.Show(text, caption, buttons, icon, defButton);
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(string text, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defButton, MessageBoxOptions options)
    {
        Initialize();
        return MessageBox.Show(text, caption, buttons, icon, defButton, options);
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, string text)
    {
        _owner = owner;
        Initialize();
        return MessageBox.Show(owner, text);
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, string text, string caption)
    {
        _owner = owner;
        Initialize();
        return MessageBox.Show(owner, text, caption);
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, string text, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons)
    {
        _owner = owner;
        Initialize();
        return MessageBox.Show(owner, text, caption, buttons);
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, string text, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon)
    {
        _owner = owner;
        Initialize();
        return MessageBox.Show(owner, text, caption, buttons, icon);
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, string text, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defButton)
    {
        _owner = owner;
        Initialize();
        return MessageBox.Show(owner, text, caption, buttons, icon, defButton);
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, string text, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defButton, MessageBoxOptions options)
    {
        _owner = owner;
        Initialize();
        return MessageBox.Show(owner, text, caption, buttons, icon,
                               defButton, options);
    }

    public delegate IntPtr HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public delegate void TimerProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, UIntPtr nIDEvent, uint dwTime);

    public const int WH_CALLWNDPROCRET = 12;

    public enum CbtHookAction : int
    {
        HCBT_MOVESIZE = 0,
        HCBT_MINMAX = 1,
        HCBT_QS = 2,
        HCBT_CREATEWND = 3,
        HCBT_DESTROYWND = 4,
        HCBT_ACTIVATE = 5,
        HCBT_CLICKSKIPPED = 6,
        HCBT_KEYSKIPPED = 7,
        HCBT_SYSCOMMAND = 8,
        HCBT_SETFOCUS = 9
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rectangle lpRect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern UIntPtr SetTimer(IntPtr hWnd, UIntPtr nIDEvent, uint uElapse, TimerProc lpTimerFunc);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr idHook);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int maxLength);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int EndDialog(IntPtr hDlg, IntPtr nResult);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct CWPRETSTRUCT
    {
        public IntPtr lResult;
        public IntPtr lParam;
        public IntPtr wParam;
        public uint message;
        public IntPtr hwnd;
    } ;

    static void MessageBoxEx()
    {
        _hookProc = new HookProc(MessageBoxHookProc);
        _hHook = IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    private static void Initialize()
    {
        if (_hHook != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("multiple calls are not supported");
        }

        if (_owner != null)
        {
            _hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, _hookProc, IntPtr.Zero, AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId());
        }
    }

    private static IntPtr MessageBoxHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode < 0)
        {
            return CallNextHookEx(_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        CWPRETSTRUCT msg = (CWPRETSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(CWPRETSTRUCT));
        IntPtr hook = _hHook;

        if (msg.message == (int)CbtHookAction.HCBT_ACTIVATE)
        {
            try
            {
                CenterWindow(msg.hwnd);
            }
            finally
            {
                UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hHook);
                _hHook = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    private static void CenterWindow(IntPtr hChildWnd)
    {
        Rectangle recChild = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
        bool success = GetWindowRect(hChildWnd, ref recChild);

        int width = recChild.Width - recChild.X;
        int height = recChild.Height - recChild.Y;

        Rectangle recParent = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
        success = GetWindowRect(_owner.Handle, ref recParent);

        Point ptCenter = new Point(0, 0);
        ptCenter.X = recParent.X + ((recParent.Width - recParent.X) / 2);
        ptCenter.Y = recParent.Y + ((recParent.Height - recParent.Y) / 2);


        Point ptStart = new Point(0, 0);
        ptStart.X = (ptCenter.X - (width / 2));
        ptStart.Y = (ptCenter.Y - (height / 2));

        ptStart.X = (ptStart.X < 0) ? 0 : ptStart.X;
        ptStart.Y = (ptStart.Y < 0) ? 0 : ptStart.Y;

        int result = MoveWindow(hChildWnd, ptStart.X, ptStart.Y, width,
                                height, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: +1, this is the correct answer - it works perfectly!  Call: `MessageBoxEx.Show(this, "Please fix the validation errors before saving.", "Validation Errors");`

Comment: do you know how to keep it working and suppress the warning for `AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()`? `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`  doesn't do it ?

Comment: ok I fixed the warning - you have to add this above the `_owner` declaration: `[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]`...`static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);` then these 3 lines "replace" things at the warning for `AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId()`: `uint processID = 0;`...`IntPtr ptr = _owner.Handle;`...`_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, _hookProc, IntPtr.Zero, (int) GetWindowThreadProcessId(ptr, out processID));` sorry for the lack of line breaks it's the best I can do

Comment: This doesn't work if you have two monitors... and drag it away from your primary monitor the messagebox shows up right at the edge of the primary monitor instead of in the center of your app.

Comment: @cb88 nope, you're right. And it doesn't work on my triple monitors now either, nor will it work in 5 yrs time on your wearable iris ;) time's a changing...

Comment: This does not seem to work in WPF apps. :-(

Comment: Does not work on .NET 5 winforms

Comment: Part 1 (fixes to the above code), add this P/Invoke function declaration:
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

Comment: Part 2 (fixes to above code), remove "MessageBoxEx" constructor. Replace existing Initialize function with this:
private static void Initialize()
{
    if (_hookProc == null)
    {
        _hookProc = new HookProc(MessageBoxHookProc);
        _hHook = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (_owner != null)
        {
            uint processID = 0;
            IntPtr ptr = _owner.Handle;
            uint iThreadId =  GetWindowThreadProcessId(ptr, out processID);
            _hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, _hookProc, IntPtr.Zero, iThreadId);
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 16):

But why stop with MessageBox-specific implementation? Use the class below like this:

```
    private void OnFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dg;
        using (DialogCenteringService centeringService = new DialogCenteringService(this)) // center message box
        {
            dg = MessageBox.Show(this, "Are you sure?", "Confirm exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        }

        if (dg == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

The code that you can use with anything that shows dialog windows, even if they're owned by another thread (our app has multiple UI threads):

([Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6122631) is the updated code which takes monitor working areas into account, so that the dialog isn't centered between two monitors or is partly off-screen. With it you'll need `enum SetWindowPosFlags`, which is below)

```
public class DialogCenteringService : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IWin32Window owner;
    private readonly HookProc hookProc;
    private readonly IntPtr hHook = IntPtr.Zero;

    public DialogCenteringService(IWin32Window owner)
    {
        if (owner == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("owner");

        this.owner = owner;
        hookProc = DialogHookProc;

        hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, hookProc, IntPtr.Zero, GetCurrentThreadId());
    }

    private IntPtr DialogHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode < 0)
        {
            return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        CWPRETSTRUCT msg = (CWPRETSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(CWPRETSTRUCT));
        IntPtr hook = hHook;

        if (msg.message == (int)CbtHookAction.HCBT_ACTIVATE)
        {
            try
            {
                CenterWindow(msg.hwnd);
            }
            finally
            {
                UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
            }
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
    }

    private void CenterWindow(IntPtr hChildWnd)
    {
        Rectangle recChild = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
        bool success = GetWindowRect(hChildWnd, ref recChild);

        if (!success)
        {
            return;
        }

        int width = recChild.Width - recChild.X;
        int height = recChild.Height - recChild.Y;

        Rectangle recParent = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
        success = GetWindowRect(owner.Handle, ref recParent);

        if (!success)
        {
            return;
        }

        Point ptCenter = new Point(0, 0);
        ptCenter.X = recParent.X + ((recParent.Width - recParent.X) / 2);
        ptCenter.Y = recParent.Y + ((recParent.Height - recParent.Y) / 2);


        Point ptStart = new Point(0, 0);
        ptStart.X = (ptCenter.X - (width / 2));
        ptStart.Y = (ptCenter.Y - (height / 2));

        //MoveWindow(hChildWnd, ptStart.X, ptStart.Y, width, height, false);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SetWindowPos(hChildWnd, (IntPtr)0, ptStart.X, ptStart.Y, width, height, SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS | SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOSIZE | SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOACTIVATE | SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOZORDER));
    }

    // some p/invoke

    // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
    public delegate IntPtr HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public delegate void TimerProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, UIntPtr nIDEvent, uint dwTime);

    private const int WH_CALLWNDPROCRET = 12;

    // ReSharper disable EnumUnderlyingTypeIsInt
    private enum CbtHookAction : int
    // ReSharper restore EnumUnderlyingTypeIsInt
    {
        // ReSharper disable UnusedMember.Local
        HCBT_MOVESIZE = 0,
        HCBT_MINMAX = 1,
        HCBT_QS = 2,
        HCBT_CREATEWND = 3,
        HCBT_DESTROYWND = 4,
        HCBT_ACTIVATE = 5,
        HCBT_CLICKSKIPPED = 6,
        HCBT_KEYSKIPPED = 7,
        HCBT_SYSCOMMAND = 8,
        HCBT_SETFOCUS = 9
        // ReSharper restore UnusedMember.Local
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rectangle lpRect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, SetWindowPosFlags uFlags);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern UIntPtr SetTimer(IntPtr hWnd, UIntPtr nIDEvent, uint uElapse, TimerProc lpTimerFunc);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr idHook);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int maxLength);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int EndDialog(IntPtr hDlg, IntPtr nResult);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct CWPRETSTRUCT
    {
        public IntPtr lResult;
        public IntPtr lParam;
        public IntPtr wParam;
        public uint message;
        public IntPtr hwnd;
    };
    // ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
}

[Flags]
public enum SetWindowPosFlags : uint
{
    // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming

    /// <summary>
    ///     If the calling thread and the thread that owns the window are attached to different input queues, the system posts the request to the thread that owns the window. This prevents the calling thread from blocking its execution while other threads process the request.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS = 0x4000,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Prevents generation of the WM_SYNCPAINT message.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_DEFERERASE = 0x2000,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Draws a frame (defined in the window's class description) around the window.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_DRAWFRAME = 0x0020,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Applies new frame styles set using the SetWindowLong function. Sends a WM_NCCALCSIZE message to the window, even if the window's size is not being changed. If this flag is not specified, WM_NCCALCSIZE is sent only when the window's size is being changed.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Hides the window.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_HIDEWINDOW = 0x0080,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Does not activate the window. If this flag is not set, the window is activated and moved to the top of either the topmost or non-topmost group (depending on the setting of the hWndInsertAfter parameter).
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Discards the entire contents of the client area. If this flag is not specified, the valid contents of the client area are saved and copied back into the client area after the window is sized or repositioned.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOCOPYBITS = 0x0100,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Retains the current position (ignores X and Y parameters).
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Does not change the owner window's position in the Z order.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = 0x0200,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Does not redraw changes. If this flag is set, no repainting of any kind occurs. This applies to the client area, the nonclient area (including the title bar and scroll bars), and any part of the parent window uncovered as a result of the window being moved. When this flag is set, the application must explicitly invalidate or redraw any parts of the window and parent window that need redrawing.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOREDRAW = 0x0008,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Same as the SWP_NOOWNERZORDER flag.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOREPOSITION = 0x0200,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Prevents the window from receiving the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING message.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOSENDCHANGING = 0x0400,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Retains the current size (ignores the cx and cy parameters).
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Retains the current Z order (ignores the hWndInsertAfter parameter).
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Displays the window.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040,

    // ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
}
```

Comment: There are issues with your positioning code. It derives from the issues with mixing a managed `Rectangle` and a native `RECT`. I posted the fix on the github repo down in the comments.

Comment: @Andy Unfortunately, I don't see any links to the fix

Comment: it's not a link -- it's the actual code posted as a comment on your github page. Here is a link: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6122631#gistcomment-3064728

Answer (score 6):

I have changed a little bit previous answer and compose WPF version of the MessageBoxEx. This code works for me great. Feel free to notify about issues of the code.

Please note:
I use `GeneralObjects.MainWindowInstance` at ctor to initialize class with my main window, but actually I use it for any window due to some kind of cache for last parent window. Therefore you can simple remove out everything from ctor.

```
public class MessageBoxEx
{
    private static HwndSource source_ = null;
    private static HwndSourceHook hook_ = null;

    static MessageBoxEx()
    {
        try
        {
            // create cached 
            createHwndSource_(GeneralObjects.MainWindowInstance);

            hook_ = new HwndSourceHook(HwndSourceHook);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (null == source_ ||
                null == hook_)
            {
                source_ = null;
                hook_ = null;
            }
        }


    }

    private static void createHwndSource_(Window owner)
    {
        source_ = (HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromVisual(owner);
    }

    public static void Initialize_(Window owner = null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (null != owner)
            {
                if(source_.RootVisual != owner)
                {
                    createHwndSource_(owner);
                }

            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (null == source_ ||
                null == hook_)
            {
                source_ = null;
                hook_ = null;
            }
        }


        if (null != source_ &&
            null != hook_)
        {
            source_.AddHook(hook_);
        }

    }

    public static MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText)
    {
        Initialize_();
        return System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText);
    }


    public static MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption)
    {
        Initialize_();
        return System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption);
    }


    public static MessageBoxResult Show(Window owner, string messageBoxText)
    {
        Initialize_(owner);
        return System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(owner, messageBoxText);
    }


    public static MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button)
    {
        Initialize_();
        return System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button);
    }


    public static MessageBoxResult Show(Window owner, string messageBoxText, string caption)
    {
        Initialize_(owner);
        return System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(owner, messageBoxText, caption);
    }


    public static MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxImage icon)
    {
        Initialize_();
        return System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon);
    }


    public static MessageBoxResult Show(Window owner, string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button)
    {
        Initialize_(owner);
        return System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(owner, messageBoxText, caption, button);
    }


    public static MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxImage icon, MessageBoxResult defaultResult)
    {
        Initialize_();
        return System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon, defaultResult);
    }


    public static MessageBoxResult Show(Window owner, string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxImage icon)
    {
        Initialize_(owner);
        return System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(owner, messageBoxText, caption, button, icon);
    }


    public static MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxImage icon, MessageBoxResult defaultResult, System.Windows.MessageBoxOptions options)
    {
        Initialize_();
        return System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon, defaultResult, options);
    }


    public static MessageBoxResult Show(Window owner, string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxImage icon, MessageBoxResult defaultResult)
    {
        Initialize_(owner);
        return System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(owner, messageBoxText, caption, button, icon, defaultResult);
    }


    public static MessageBoxResult Show(Window owner, string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxImage icon, MessageBoxResult defaultResult, System.Windows.MessageBoxOptions options)
    {
        Initialize_(owner);
        return System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(owner, messageBoxText, caption, button, icon, defaultResult, options);
    }

    private enum WM : int
    {
        WM_ACTIVATE = 0x0006
    }

    private static IntPtr HwndSourceHook(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {

        if ((int)WM.WM_ACTIVATE == msg &&
            source_.Handle == hwnd &&
            0 == (int)wParam)
        {

            try
            {
                CenterWindow(lParam);
            }
            finally
            {
                // remove hook at once after moved message box window.
                source_.RemoveHook(hook_);
            }
        }
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rectangle lpRect);


    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

    private static void CenterWindow(IntPtr hChildWnd)
    {
        System.Drawing.Rectangle recChild = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

        bool success = GetWindowRect(hChildWnd, ref recChild);

        int width = recChild.Width - recChild.X;
        int height = recChild.Height - recChild.Y;

        System.Drawing.Rectangle recParent = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
        success = GetWindowRect(source_.Handle, ref recParent);

        System.Drawing.Point ptCenter = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        ptCenter.X = recParent.X + ((recParent.Width - recParent.X) / 2);
        ptCenter.Y = recParent.Y + ((recParent.Height - recParent.Y) / 2);


        System.Drawing.Point ptStart = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        ptStart.X = (ptCenter.X - (width / 2));
        ptStart.Y = (ptCenter.Y - (height / 2));

        // I have commented this code because of I have 2 monitors
        // so If application located at 1st monitor
        // message box can appear at second one.

        /*
        ptStart.X = (ptStart.X < 0) ? 0 : ptStart.X;
        ptStart.Y = (ptStart.Y < 0) ? 0 : ptStart.Y;
        */

        int result = MoveWindow(hChildWnd, ptStart.X, ptStart.Y, width,
                                height, false);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this, it's simple enough to justify the time...

This is for Win32 API, written in C. Translate it as you need...

```
case WM_NOTIFY:{
  HWND X=FindWindow("#32770",NULL);
  if(GetParent(X)==H_frame){int Px,Py,Sx,Sy; RECT R1,R2;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd,&R1); GetWindowRect(X,&R2);
    Sx=R2.right-R2.left,Px=R1.left+(R1.right-R1.left)/2-Sx/2;
    Sy=R2.bottom-R2.top,Py=R1.top+(R1.bottom-R1.top)/2-Sy/2;
    MoveWindow(X,Px,Py,Sx,Sy,1);
  }
} break;
```

Add that to the WndProc code... You can set position as you like, in this case it just centres over the main program window. It will do this for any messagebox, or file open/save dialog, and likely some other native controls. I'm not sure, but I think you may need to include COMMCTRL or COMMDLG to use this, at least, you will if you want open/save dialogs.

I experimented with looking at the notify codes and hwndFrom of NMHDR, then decided it was just as effective, and far easier, not to. If you really want to be very specific, tell FindWindow to look for a unique caption (title) you give to the window you want it to find.

This fires before the messagebox is drawn onscreen, so if you set a global flag to indicate when action is done by your code, and look for a unique caption, you be sure that actions you take will only occur once (there will likely be multiple notifiers). I haven't explored this in detail, but I managed get CreateWindow to put an edit box on a messagebox dialog. It looked as out of place as a rat's ear grafted onto the spine of a cloned pig, but it works. Doing things this way may be far easier than having to roll your own.

Crow.

EDIT: Small correction to make sure that the right window is handled. Make sure that parent handles agree throughout, and this should work ok. It does for me, even with two instances of the same program...

Answer (score 5):

Surely using your own panel or form would be by far the simplest approach if a little more heavy on the background (designer) code. It gives all the control in terms of centring and manipulation without writing all that custom code.