# Keep MessageBox from moving outside the parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I need to keep message box inside a parent form. So when the user tries to move Messagebox outside parent it stays within parent from. I have no problem doing my own message form. But I like to use Message box functionality.

Ideally I would like to add to this approach.
[center MessageBox in parent form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732443/center-messagebox-in-parent-form)

How do I capture messagebox move event and not allow it to go outside parent.

Comment: I suppose you could use this code and just keep it running: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576156/winforms-how-can-i-make-messagebox-appear-centered-on-mainform/2576220#2576220  One feature too many, frankly.

Answer (score 2):

The way to achieve this is to create your own MessageBox class, and duplicate the functionality.

As a hint: It may help to use a label with an "autosize" turned on. You can then use the size of the label to resize the MessageBox to match.

Having said that, it sounds like a bad idea. Why not just let the user move the messagebox if they want?

Comment: Agreed why not let the user move the messageBox?

Comment: My concern is if the user moves MessageBox away from the main form and comes back to main from later forgetting that MessageBox is somewhere else, my application will seem unresponsive.

Comment: I could just let them move the message box (possibly I am making too much out of this).  I understand that if the user clicks on parent message box pops back up, but on WinXp it could be hidden by a task bar.

Comment: All apps with messagebox's work this way, so yours is nothing different. I wouldn't worry about it.