# How do I display a messageBox on top of, or near its parent Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, error-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [center MessageBox in parent form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732443/center-messagebox-in-parent-form)

I am trying to make an C# application and I want to have my messageBox appear near the parent.
I tried:

```
MessageBox.Show(this,"this operation does not work");
```

And this doesn't work.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and check the value of `this`?  Also, 'doesn't work' isn't descriptive enough.  Is the `messagebox` not showing?  Are you getting an `exception`?

Comment: -1 for _And this doesn't work._

Comment: It's possible to reposition a `MessageBox`, but it's messy business. Create your own form.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Windows Forms, create a new class which extends System.Windows.Form to mimic MessageBox.   Set the Location property based on your new classes Parent.Location property.