# Winforms-How can I make MessageBox appear centered on MainForm?

Tags: winforms, messagebox

Winforms-How can I make dialog boxes appear centered on MainForm?  That is as opposed to be based on Normal windows default which renders them in the centre of the screen.

In my case I have a small main form that may for example be positioned in a corner, the the MessageBox popup is displayed what seems a ways away.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

It is possible with some servings of P/Invoke and the magic provided by Control.BeginInvoke().  Add a new class to your project and paste this code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class CenterWinDialog : IDisposable {
    private int mTries = 0;
    private Form mOwner;

    public CenterWinDialog(Form owner) {
        mOwner = owner;
        owner.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(findDialog));
    }

    private void findDialog() {
        // Enumerate windows to find the message box
        if (mTries < 0) return;
        EnumThreadWndProc callback = new EnumThreadWndProc(checkWindow);
        if (EnumThreadWindows(GetCurrentThreadId(), callback, IntPtr.Zero)) {
            if (++mTries < 10) mOwner.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(findDialog));
        }
    }
    private bool checkWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lp) {
        // Checks if <hWnd> is a dialog
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(260);
        GetClassName(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);
        if (sb.ToString() != "#32770") return true;
        // Got it
        Rectangle frmRect = new Rectangle(mOwner.Location, mOwner.Size);
        RECT dlgRect;
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, out dlgRect);
        MoveWindow(hWnd,
            frmRect.Left + (frmRect.Width - dlgRect.Right + dlgRect.Left) / 2,
            frmRect.Top + (frmRect.Height - dlgRect.Bottom + dlgRect.Top) / 2,
            dlgRect.Right - dlgRect.Left,
            dlgRect.Bottom - dlgRect.Top, true);
        return false;
    }
    public void Dispose() {
        mTries = -1;
    }

    // P/Invoke declarations
    private delegate bool EnumThreadWndProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lp);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int tid, EnumThreadWndProc callback, IntPtr lp);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder buffer, int buflen);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT rc);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int w, int h, bool repaint);
    private struct RECT { public int Left; public int Top; public int Right; public int Bottom; }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        using (new CenterWinDialog(this)) {
            MessageBox.Show("Nobugz waz here");
        }
    }
```

Note that this code works for any of the Windows dialogs.  MessageBox, OpenFormDialog, FolderBrowserDialog, PrintDialog, ColorDialog, FontDialog, PageSetupDialog, SaveFileDialog.

Comment: Thanks, very good solution. You just need to change it not to use `this` which is redundant. Simply take the top form.

Comment: The best +10000000000000

Comment: That's a mad little utility. Excellent solution.

Comment: You need one small fix on this... it messes up message boxes if the main window is minimized. This can be avoided by putting `if (owner.WindowState != FormWindowState.Minimized)` before the `owner.BeginInvoke` in the constructror, effectively disabling the system in that case.

Comment: We bow to the Master!  \<^_^>/  Most excellent Sir, the 12 kingdoms thank Thee.

Answer (score 2):

This is for Win32 API, written in C. Translate it as you need...

```
case WM_NOTIFY:{
  HWND X=FindWindow("#32770",NULL);
  if(GetParent(X)==H_frame){int Px,Py,Sx,Sy; RECT R1,R2;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd,&R1); GetWindowRect(X,&R2);
    Sx=R2.right-R2.left,Px=R1.left+(R1.right-R1.left)/2-Sx/2;
    Sy=R2.bottom-R2.top,Py=R1.top+(R1.bottom-R1.top)/2-Sy/2;
    MoveWindow(X,Px,Py,Sx,Sy,1);
  }
} break;
```

Add that to the WndProc code... You can set position as you like, in this case it just centres over the main program window. It will do this for any messagebox, or file open/save dialog, and likely some other native controls. I'm not sure, but I think you may need to include COMMCTRL or COMMDLG to use this, at least, you will if you want open/save dialogs.

I experimented with looking at the notify codes and hwndFrom of NMHDR, then decided it was just as effective, and far easier, not to. If you really want to be very specific, tell FindWindow to look for a unique caption (title) you give to the window you want it to find.

This fires before the messagebox is drawn onscreen, so if you set a global flag to indicate when action is done by your code, and look for a unique caption, you be sure that actions you take will only occur once (there will likely be multiple notifiers). I haven't explored this in detail, but I managed get CreateWindow to put an edit box on a messagebox dialog/ It looked as out of place as a rat's ear grafted onto the spine of a cloned pig, but it works. Doing things this way may be far easier than having to roll your own.

Crow.

EDIT: Small correction to make sure that the right window is handled. Make sure that parent handles agree throughout, and this should work ok. It does for me, even with two instances of the same program...

Answer (score 1):

The class proved to be applicable to two other situations. I had a FolderBrowserDialog that I wanted to be larger, and I wanted it to come up near the top-left of the parent dialog (near the button I click to open it).

I copied the CenterWinDialog class and made two new classes. One class changes the dialog size, and the other changes its position to a specific offset from the parent form. This is the usage:

```
        using (new OffsetWinDialog(this) { PreferredOffset = new Point(75, 75 )})
        using (new SizeWinDialog(this)   { PreferredSize   = new Size(400, 600)})
        {
            DialogResult result = dlgFolderBrowser.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
                return;
        }
```

and these are the two classes that were based on the original one.

```
class OffsetWinDialog : IDisposable
{
    private int mTries = 0;
    private Form mOwner;

    public OffsetWinDialog(Form owner)
    {
        mOwner = owner;
        owner.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(findDialog));
    }

    public Point PreferredOffset { get; set; }

    private void findDialog()
    {
        // Enumerate windows to find the message box
        if (mTries < 0) 
            return;
        EnumThreadWndProc callback = new EnumThreadWndProc(checkWindow);
        if (EnumThreadWindows(GetCurrentThreadId(), callback, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            if (++mTries < 10)
                mOwner.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(findDialog));
        }
    }
    private bool checkWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lp)
    {
        // Checks if <hWnd> is a dialog
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(260);
        GetClassName(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);
        if (sb.ToString() != "#32770") return true;
        // Got it
        Rectangle frmRect = new Rectangle(mOwner.Location, mOwner.Size);
        RECT dlgRect;
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, out dlgRect);
        MoveWindow(hWnd,
            frmRect.Left   + PreferredOffset.X,
            frmRect.Top    + PreferredOffset.Y,
            dlgRect.Right  - dlgRect.Left,
            dlgRect.Bottom - dlgRect.Top, 
            true);
        return false;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        mTries = -1;
    }

    // P/Invoke declarations
    private delegate bool EnumThreadWndProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lp);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int tid, EnumThreadWndProc callback, IntPtr lp);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder buffer, int buflen);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT rc);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int w, int h, bool repaint);
    private struct RECT { public int Left; public int Top; public int Right; public int Bottom; }
}
```

and

```
class SizeWinDialog : IDisposable
{
    private int mTries = 0;
    private Form mOwner;

    public SizeWinDialog(Form owner)
    {
        mOwner = owner;
        mOwner.BeginInvoke(new Action(findDialog));
    }

    public Size PreferredSize { get; set; }

    private void findDialog()
    {
        // Enumerate windows to find the message box
        if (mTries < 0) 
            return;
        EnumThreadWndProc callback = new EnumThreadWndProc(checkWindow);
        if (EnumThreadWindows(GetCurrentThreadId(), callback, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            if (++mTries < 10) 
                mOwner.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(findDialog));
        }
    }
    private bool checkWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lp)
    {
        // Checks if <hWnd> is a dialog
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(260);
        GetClassName(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);
        if (sb.ToString() != "#32770") 
            return true;
        // Got it
        Rectangle frmRect = new Rectangle(mOwner.Location, mOwner.Size);
        RECT dlgRect;
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, out dlgRect);
        SetWindowPos(new HandleRef(this, hWnd), new HandleRef(), dlgRect.Left, dlgRect.Top, PreferredSize.Width, PreferredSize.Height, 20 | 2);
        return false;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        mTries = -1;
    }

    // P/Invoke declarations
    private delegate bool EnumThreadWndProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lp);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int tid, EnumThreadWndProc callback, IntPtr lp);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder buffer, int buflen);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT rc);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern bool SetWindowPos(HandleRef hWnd, HandleRef hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy,
        int flags);

    private struct RECT { public int Left; public int Top; public int Right; public int Bottom; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your own messagebox. A form and a label should do it. Or do you also need to globalize it?

Comment: In that case you can add a label to a form and use MeasureString to get the bounds of it. Size the form appropriately and position it wherever you like. Should be quick.

But I must admit I also like Nobugz' solution.

Comment: This really overlooks the complexity involved in reproducing the many variations messageboxes can have, making the new API a "drop in" for the original, modifying all the existing code to use the replacement, etc.  Plus TBH it does not really answer the specific question.

Answer (score 0):

No need for homebrew messagebox or GetForegroundWindow, EnumWindows, AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll, SetWindowsHookEx, etc.

WM_ACTIVATE message is sent to the form when the message box is opened or closed.
Then you can get the window handle of the message box (LParam).

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch (m.Msg) {
    case Pinvoke.WM_ACTIVATE:
        Debug.WriteLine($"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name} {DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")} {m.ToString()}");
        if (m.LParam == IntPtr.Zero) break;
        if (_messageBoxCaption == null) break; // donot call MessageBox.Show
        if ((ushort)m.WParam.ToInt32() != 0/*WA_INACTIVE*/) break; // maybe close messagebox

        // check messagebox
        if (Pinvoke.GetWindowProcessId(m.LParam) != Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id) break;
        string className = Pinvoke.GetClassName(m.LParam);
        if (className == null || className != "#32770") break; // not dialog
        if (_messageBoxCaption != Pinvoke.GetWindowText(m.LParam)) break; // another caption

        // move messagebox
        //Debug.WriteLine("messageBox detected");
        Rectangle rect = Pinvoke.GetWindowRect(m.LParam);
        Pinvoke.MoveWindow(m.LParam, this.Left + this.Width / 2, this.Top + this.Height / 2, rect.Width, rect.Height, true);
        break;
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

GetWindowProcessId is a wrapper for GetWindowThreadProcessId.
Add other Pinvoke methods as appropriate.
If you want to reduce P/Invoke as much as possible, replace them with UIAutomation.

```
private string _messageBoxCaption = null; // messageBox caption

_messageBoxCaption = caption;
ret = MessageBox.Show(this, text, caption, ...);
_messageBoxCaption = null;
```

Answer (score -2):

Create your own..

```
 public partial class __MessageBox : Form
   {
      public MMMessageBox(string title, string message)
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         this.Text = title;
         this.labelString.Text = message;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Nothing in your post handles the "centered on MainForm" issue.

Comment: Sorry Lars, then use the 'Form Property': StartPosition->CenterParent for the dialogue box you created.

Comment: @gameOverMan Now make it handle all the icons, Yes/No/OK/Cancel, default selected buttons, and `DialogResult` response cases that the original message box has. Not exactly a trivial task.