# How do I change the MessageBox location?

Tags: c#, messagebox

I need to change the message box location. I don't want it to be in the center of the page.

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello");
```

Comment: I've changed your title from `massagebox` (sounds lovely) to `messagebox`.

Comment: @jgauffin, tag `winforms` a little bit incorrect, because `MessageBox` is available in WPF too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winforms-How can I make MessageBox appear centered on MainForm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576156/winforms-how-can-i-make-messagebox-appear-centered-on-mainform)

Answer (score 14):

Normally, you can't change startup location of standard message box.

Solutions for your question:

- Create your own custom message box.
  There is example of creation on
  [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/A_Custom_Message_Box.aspx).
- Complicated way using [Windows Hook
  Procedure (WinAPI)](https://web.archive.org/web/20131128023424/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180936) (KB180936).

Comment: Your link to the Windows Hook Procedure is broken.

Comment: @user2163234 updated to archived copy

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a new form that inherits from the MessageBox form. That is the only way to access the position properties.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to change the location, but its way too complicated for such a small task. 
If you really need to change its location, you could display it, then use `GetForegroundWindow` to get a window handle, then `MoveWindow` to your desired location. 
But, as I already mensioned, this is way too complicated. 
 Just create your own form with a label on it an a "OK" button. Set the button as the default window button, and then, in Form1 do `MyWndName.ShowDialog();`

Comment: you can't be ensure that `GetForegroundWindow` will give you handle of created message box. Possible happen that another application will go to foreground in that moment.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to create a new window, set the property AllowsTransparency to true and set the Background to Transparent. In that window you can put a TextBlock, or a label and also add Yes/No Buttons. Set the location of this window using Canvs.SetTop(Window,TopPosition) and Canvas.SetLeft(Window,LeftPosition). next, call the window with the method Show() or ShowDialog().

Answer (score 1):

Since I already use AutoIt for several other tasks in my project so I just create another thread to move the Message box

```
using System.Threading;
using AutoIt;
//Namespace, class, function stuffs
//New thread BEFORE create message box - safety measure
Thread autoItThread = new Thread(delegate ()
                {
                    AutoItX.WinWait("New Message box");
                    AutoItX.WinMove("New Message box", "This box will be moved", 400, 300);
                });
                autoItThread.Start();
MessageBox.Show("This box will be moved", "New Message box");
```

Please note

- The coordinate `400,300` is absolute. `0,0` will be top left corner.
- This is screen-dependent. If you want to be exact, other code to determine location is needed
- This task is to change the absolute position of the Message box rather than move it.
- How to get/install AutoIt is not addressed here. Please look for instruction on that if you need to.