# How do I do MessageBox.Show on primary screen?

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

Is there any possibility to show a `MessageBox` on the Primary Screen, not necessarily on the screen where the application is running?

Comment: winforms (see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.primaryscreen(v=vs.110).aspx) and your next question will be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5289148/1997232))? wpf?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you have multiple monitors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try `MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly`:

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello World", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
```

Works pretty well for me, but doesn't render the message box with the default visual style of Windows.

Comment: This is probably the easiest way but it will cause the messagebox to be displayed without visual styles. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxoptions(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I just tried that. It needs to disable owner for use DefaultDesktopOnly ( MessageBox.Show(this, "blahblah",..., MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly) -> MessageBox.Show( "blahblah",..., MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly) ) Then it appears on right desktop (yes, multiple monitors). It works fine (topmost of parrent works now without owner (this). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is not an easy way to do it, but here is one way:

First create a Form or Window that is very small (1x1) or something. Make sure that this Form opens up on the primary display. You can get the primary display dimensions by using the [Screen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object. Make sure to set the properties of the form so it doesn't show up in the task bar.

Then call Messagebox.Show and pass in the Form.Handle to the show method. This tells the system to display the messagebox in front of that object. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cked7698(v=vs.110).aspx

Last, make sure to close the form you opened immediately after the Show call so that it doesn't create zombie forms.