# popup message box destination Monitor

Tags: c#, windows, popup

I wrote a windows service to capture print event and then popup a message box to notify user to aware about environment protection.

The program is written in C#.

It work fine. However, a problem occur if user computer have more than 1 monitors.
For example:
I execute MS word on monitor A and then I click on print button, the popup message box would be popup on monitor B.
Is it possible to control the message box would be popup on monitor A?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289148/how-do-i-change-the-messagebox-location

Comment: MessageBox.Show("Hello World", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);

Comment: I need to write a windows service, not normal windows application.