# How do I make it so it puts message boxes looping in random locations

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make it so it puts messages boxes on the screen looped 5 times and I want the message box in a different location each time a message box appears. I think it would be pretty cool. Here is my code.

```
Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            r.Next(MessageBox.Show("hello world."));
        }
```

if anyone can please help me, that would be great :D

Comment: .net's `MessageBox` is a wrapper around User32.dll MessageBoxW. Not impossible, but very ugly https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/765f5da6-6d20-4645-a365-e996aa150eef/messagebox-position?forum=winforms

Comment: I believe this was answered here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289148/how-do-i-change-the-messagebox-location