# Show msgbox in the center of the panel on the form

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, msgbox

Good afternoon!
Tell me, is it possible to place msgbox in the center of the panel on the form? or is it easier to create a form as a message and call it centered?

Comment: Why is this tagged c# _and_ vb.net? Which UI stack are you using? WinForms, WPF, something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the MessageBox location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289148/how-do-i-change-the-messagebox-location)

Comment: [How can I make MessageBox appear centered on MainForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2576220/7444103) -- You can probably simplify the procedure using UI Automation's `WindowPatter.WindowOpened` event, to detect when the MessageBox Window is shown, then move it where you please, automatically (using the Event Handler). -- You can further simplify it by building your own MessageBoxes.

Comment: You can also use [SetWinEventHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) registering [EVENT_SYSTEM_DIALOGSTART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/event-constants), it will notify you when a Dialog is started, returning its Handle. You can then move it with `SetWindowPos()`. You can use the same procedure described here: [Move window when external application's window moves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48812831/7444103), just replacing `EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to center a `MessageBox` in your `Panel`, but it's much easier to create a custom one. This might help you, you can play around with the `Location`, the `Size` and the other properties.

```
var myMessageBox = new Form
            {
                StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
                ShowInTaskbar = false,
                Size = new Size(400, 180),
                Location = new Point(this.Location.X + panel1.Location.X + panel1.Width / 2 - 200, this.Location.Y + panel1.Location.Y + panel1.Height / 2 - 90),
                Text = "MessageBox",
                ShowIcon = false,
            };

            Label label = new Label
            {
                Name = "label",
                Text = "Some text.",
                AutoSize = true,
                MaximumSize = new Size (myMessageBox.Width - 30, myMessageBox.Height),
                Location = new Point(10, 65)
            };
            myMessageBox.Controls.Add(label);

            myMessageBox.ShowDialog();
```