# How to specify the position for a MessageBox to appear in C?

Tags: c, winapi, messagebox

So, I know how to create a MessageBox in C, but it makes it only appear in the center of the screen. How can I specify the ***x*** and ***y*** coordinates for the MessageBox?

Comment: Assuming you mean the Windows API function with that name, then check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289148/how-do-i-change-the-messagebox-location. (That's C# but this isn't really related to the programming language)

Comment: Maybe MessageBox isn't the solution to your problem, if you need more than a MessageBox.

Comment: `MessageBox` not design for specify the x and y coordinates, and many another features. only for standard and very simple UI with minimal coding. if you need more - use own dialog. if very want - you can use `WH_CBT` for change initial position of dialog

Comment: The linked duplicate was for C# and offered no solution that could be applied to C.  I have now linked in a different duplicate that can be applied to C.