How to center message box in c# based on the postion of the windows form?
My windows form is showing at the bottom right corner of my screen. I used the following code in form load event to show the form at bottom right corner and it is working perfectly
Rectangle workingArea = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this);
this.Location = new Point(workingArea.Right - Size.Width,
                          workingArea.Bottom - Size.Height);

Now I want to show the message box at the center of this bottom-right aligned form. How do i do that ?
I passed 'this' to the messageBox.Show (     ) function
MessageBox.Show(this, "Hello")

Similar question asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289148/how-do-i-change-the-messagebox-location

You need to create custom message box and then set the position accordingly. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17253/A-Custom-Message-Box

If using .NET Core 5 or higher see .NET Core TaskDialog
