# How to set position of FolderBrowserDialog to center of parent?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show a FolderBrowserDialog in center of a parent window. But if the parent window is in full-screen mode, then the FolderBrowserDialog can't show in the center (I think this is impacted by the taskbar).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winforms-How can I make MessageBox appear centered on MainForm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576156/winforms-how-can-i-make-messagebox-appear-centered-on-mainform)