# Is there any way to align text in message box in vb or vba?

Tags: vba, vb6, vbscript, messagebox

Is there any way to align text into the center in `msgbox` in VB or VBA? Does VB have any functionality to do the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The `MsgBox()` function is simply a wrapper for the Windows [`MessageBox()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and as such has no stylistic control over the dialog beyond the icon.

If you want to change it any further than this, you will need to create your own window and show that instead.

On Windows Vista+ you can use [TaskDialogs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787471%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that allow a lot more control.

Comment: TaskDialogs have been around since Vista.  Keep in mind how small a change Win7 really is.

Comment: Ah, I forgot when they were introduced. My answer's been updated to suit.

Comment: I think the absolute "No" here is incorrect. VB itself obviously does not support this directly but I would think a workaround such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/10760568/3195477 would work equally well in VB6.

Comment: @StayOnTarget that question and answer centers the dialog over the window, not the text in the dialog which is being asked here.

Answer (score 4):

no, but you can cheat by using spaces.

```
msgbox("                your message")
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are building your strings you could pad them at the beginning and end with spaces to achieve a target length. If you're using excel the worksheet function rept is handy for this.

```
function pad_n_center(byval mystring as string, lenmax as integer) as string
    dim pad_by as integer
    dim pad as string
    pad_by = (lenmax - len(mystring))/2
    'some more code to finesse that?
    pad = worksheetfunction.rept(" ",pad_by)
    pad_n_center = pad & mystring & pad
end function
```

As mentioned before if the msgbox still doesn't look good you can use textbox shape object (or other objects) to get the desired effect.

Comment: Not sure why you would need the right pad but pretty useful

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Padding the right could keep the box at max width

Answer (score 1):

VBA

Some notes: http://access.mvps.org/access/bugs/bugs0035.htm AND http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=435428 However, it is not so difficult to build your own message box, which solves all your problems.

Answer (score 1):

you probably can use a combinatrion vbtab and controlchars.CrLf in the message box.

Comment: Please add more description to the answer on how to do this. Probably adding some images of successful attempt would help improving the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to "center" an Application.Input box:  When the box opens, with the mouse move the box where you want it to open in the future and it does just that.  It opens where you last position it.  At least that; what it does for me.