# Possible to check a window for pop-up dialog boxes?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, dialog

If I have a Process ID or MainWindowHandle, is it possible to check that window for any pop-up dialog boxes?  99% of them are created using Messagebox.Show().

The idea is that we have about 50 PCs that are semi-automated but certain applications throw error pop-up messages and I'd like to write a monitoring application that checks every PC for possible errors, etc.

Comment: The code you need is in the findDialog() method in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576156/winforms-how-can-i-make-messagebox-appear-centered-on-mainform/2576220#2576220