# Capture WindowClass #32770

Tags: c#

I am new in C#, i've got some problem to capture any windows dialog show in my server. I need to know the message (caption and title) from windows dialog so i can write to my application log.

I know that i must find #32770 class windows, but i do not know how to enumwindows. In delphi 7, the code should use some functions like:

- Enumwindows
- EnumProcess
- Enumchildwindows
- Enumchildwindowsproc
- Getwindowthreadprocessid
- GetClassName
- Getwindowtext

Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: You'll see an example of findDialog in [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576156/winforms-how-can-i-make-messagebox-appear-centered-on-mainform/2576220#2576220).  Trying to tinker with other programs when you are just starting out learning how to program is a very common goal.  Always a bad idea however, you have to learn *three* brand-new things.  Keep the winapi and pinvoke on the shelf for a while until you've mastered C# first.

Comment: @Hans Passant thanks you for your suggestions. C# likes a new jungle to me. Very different from pascal - delphi or vb classic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use windows API in C# as well. You can find a lot information and examples of using [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindowEx.html). And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is information about `DllImport` attribute.

You can try something like:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, string windowTitle);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var handle = IntPtr.Zero;
        do
        {
            handle = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, handle, "#32770", null);
            if (handle != IntPtr.Zero )
                Console.WriteLine("Found handle: {0:X}", handle.ToInt64());
        } while (handle != IntPtr.Zero);


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: is this findwindowex will capture all window dialog ? (i.e. if i open task manager and Date and Time Properties, with findwindowex, i will get 2 #32770 class window. is that right ?

Comment: @Mangs Yes, see my updated answer. It shows how to enum all such windows.

Comment: Thanks, with this code, i also get title and child's caption too.