# Get modal dialog handle for PrintDialog

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I have an windows app on .net 2.0. On `Form1`, I open a `PrintDialog`. How can I get that dialog's handle from my code?

I have tried a lot of win32 functions: `EnumWindows`, `EnumChildWindows`, `FindWindow`, `FindWindowEx` but it cannot find my `PrintDialog`. All I can find is just `Form1` and its children are controls on it. There's no way I can get `PrintDialog's` handle.

Some code that i have tried:

Import win32:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
```

calling win32 functions:

```
using (PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog
                                 {
                                     AllowCurrentPage = false,
                                     AllowSomePages = true,
                                     AllowSelection = false
                                 })
{    
      IntPtr printHandle = CustomPrintDialog.FindWindow("#32770", "Print");
      // some logic with printHandle go here
      if (dlg.ShowDialog(this)==DialogResult.OK){
          // some logic go here
      }
}
```

I have checked with Spy++, there is still a `PrintDialog` window. That `PrintDialog` window has Parent Window's handle exactly same as `Form1's` handle.

Does anyone can help me to get a `PrintDialog's` handle from its parent window?

Comment: Sample code [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2576220/17034).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that underlying window for the `PrintDialog` is created during the execution of the `ShowDialog` method. It does not exist before this method's invocation, that's why you cannot find the window.
So you must inject your work on `PrintDialog` handle inside `ShowDialog`. This can be achieved with the help of `Control.BeginInvoke` method:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ...

    private ShowPrintDialog()
    {
        using (var pd = new PrintDialog())
        {
            BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(TweakPrintDialog));
            if (pd.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // printing
            }
        }
    }

    private void TweakPrintDialog()
    {
        var printDialogHandle = GetActiveWindow();
        // do your tweaking here
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();
}
```

Another problem is to find `PrintDialog` window. `GetActiveWindow` is really a straightforward way to accomplish this, because the dialog is expected to be active while `ShowDialog` is in action.
The more reliable solution may include enumerating top-level windows and analyzing their owners and/or other props. Here is one possible approach, assuming that print dialog is the only window at the moment that is owned by the form. The `TweakPrintDialog` method from the previous snippet is modified:

```
    private void TweakPrintDialog()
    {
        uint processId;
        var threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(this.Handle, out processId);
        EnumThreadWindows(threadId, FindPrintDialog, IntPtr.Zero);
        // printDialogHandle field now contains the found handle
        // do your tweaking here
    }

    private IntPtr printDialogHandle;

    private bool FindPrintDialog(IntPtr handle, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (GetWindow(handle, GW_OWNER) == this.Handle)
        {
            printDialogHandle = handle;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

    private delegate bool EnumWindowProc(IntPtr handle, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(uint threadId, EnumWindowProc enumProc, IntPtr lParam);

    private const uint GW_OWNER = 4;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr handle, uint cmd);
```

Comment: Exactly what i need. After reading some samples i know i cannot find a dialog before showdialog it but i don't know how to deal with it. Your answer totally solved my problem.

Comment: Tried this on a FolderBrowserDialog, the window enumeration produces one item, GetWindow on it returns a zero.  The window walking is being triggered before the dialog actually shows up.