# Messagebox customization is not shown correctly

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, winapi, messagebox

Time ago I've taken [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576156/winforms-how-can-i-make-messagebox-appear-centered-on-mainform) of @Hans Passant to make some modifications, all works fine but now I've noticed that the custom messagebox is not shown properly.

This is how its shown a normal messagebox with my custom windows theme:
[image]

And this else is how its shown the custom messagebox:
[image]

As you can see the darkened bottom layer in the custom messagebox is not properly alligned or resized or I don't know.

How I can fix this issue?, this is the full code:

```
' [ Centered MessageBox ]
'
' The author of the original code is Hans Passant: 
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576156/winforms-how-can-i-make-messagebox-appear-centered-on-mainform
'
' Examples :
'
' Using New CenteredMessageBox(Me, New Font(New FontFamily("Lucida Console"), Font.SizeInPoints, FontStyle.Bold))
'     MessageBox.Show("Test Text", "Test Title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
' End Using

#Region " Centered MessageBox Class"

Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Class CenteredMessageBox : Implements IDisposable

    Private mTries As Integer = 0
    Private mOwner As Form
    Private mFont As Font

    ' P/Invoke declarations
    Private Const WM_SETFONT As Integer = &H30
    Private Const WM_GETFONT As Integer = &H31

    Private Delegate Function EnumThreadWndProc(hWnd As IntPtr, lp As IntPtr) As Boolean

    Friend Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal wFlags As UInt32) As Boolean

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Private Shared Function EnumThreadWindows(tid As Integer, callback As EnumThreadWndProc, lp As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")>
    Private Shared Function GetCurrentThreadId() As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Private Shared Function GetClassName(hWnd As IntPtr, buffer As StringBuilder, buflen As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Private Shared Function GetDlgItem(hWnd As IntPtr, item As Integer) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, msg As Integer, wp As IntPtr, lp As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Shared Function GetWindowRect(hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef rc As RECT) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Shared Function MoveWindow(hWnd As IntPtr, x As Integer, y As Integer, w As Integer, h As Integer, repaint As Boolean) As Boolean
    End Function

    Structure RECT
        Public Left As Integer
        Public Top As Integer
        Public Right As Integer
        Public Bottom As Integer
    End Structure

    Public Sub New(owner As Form, Optional Custom_Font As Font = Nothing)
        mOwner = owner
        mFont = Custom_Font
        owner.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf findDialog))
    End Sub

    Private Sub findDialog()

        ' Enumerate windows to find the message box
        If mTries < 0 Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim callback As New EnumThreadWndProc(AddressOf checkWindow)

        If EnumThreadWindows(GetCurrentThreadId(), callback, IntPtr.Zero) Then
            If System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(mTries) < 10 Then
                mOwner.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf findDialog))
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Function checkWindow(hWnd As IntPtr, lp As IntPtr) As Boolean

        ' Checks if <hWnd> is a dialog
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder(260)
        GetClassName(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity)
        If sb.ToString() <> "#32770" Then Return True

        ' Get the STATIC control that displays the text
        Dim hText As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, &HFFFF)

        Dim frmRect As New Rectangle(mOwner.Location, mOwner.Size)
        Dim dlgRect As RECT
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, dlgRect)

        If hText <> IntPtr.Zero Then

            If mFont Is Nothing Then
                ' Get the current font
                mFont = Font.FromHfont(SendMessage(hText, WM_GETFONT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
            End If

            SendMessage(hText, WM_SETFONT, mFont.ToHfont(), New IntPtr(1))

            ' Resize and positionate the messagebox window:
            MoveWindow(hWnd, _
                       frmRect.Left + (frmRect.Width - dlgRect.Right + dlgRect.Left) \ 2, _
                       frmRect.Top + (frmRect.Height - dlgRect.Bottom + dlgRect.Top) \ 2, _
                       (dlgRect.Right - dlgRect.Left), _
                       (dlgRect.Bottom - dlgRect.Top), True)

            ' Resize the MessageBox Text Label
            If mFont IsNot Nothing Then
                SetWindowPos(hText, 0, 70, 35, 1920, 1080, 0)
            End If

        End If

        ' Done
        Return False

    End Function

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        mTries = -1
        mOwner = Nothing
        If mFont IsNot Nothing Then mFont.Dispose()
    End Sub

End Class

#End Region
```

Comment: time ago I told you that winforms doesn't support anything, and you insisted in using that archaic stuff anyways. Now you're stuck with all these horrible hacks and unexpected unpredictable results until you face reality and start using relevant technology from this century. Too bad...

Comment: Yes, I know HighCore, as I have always said your advice is very good, but at least and by the moment learn WPF should be very more professional (and will take very more long time) than my current software needs, or I think so. thanks for comment

Comment: not related to the question, but how did you manage to style Winform MessageBox ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the code to resize the text label is causing the problem

```
        ' Resize the MessageBox Text Label
        If mFont IsNot Nothing Then
            SetWindowPos(hText, 0, 70, 35, 1920, 1080, 0)
        End If
```

This code resizes the text label to a very large size and covers the lower area. If you change the height from 1080 to something smaller, like 30, the problem disappears.

I was also able to get it to work by removing this If statement entirely. The MessageBox is still centered in the parent form and appears to work correctly without it.