# Message Box hidden in task bar in win form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winforms-interop

I have a win form containing only progress bar and 
logic for opening and closing an excel or word document using interopt dll.
This win form runs when I click a button in my web application.
The problem is, the win form after closing document displays a Message Box.
This message box always remains in the taskbar instead of Showing up in the 
screen.

PS:

```
DialogResult Result = MessageBox.Show("Save","Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

When I give the message box in this format, the message box always remains in the taskbar. But the functionalities given as properties for the message box works fine.

```
DialogResult Result = MessageBox.Show("Save","Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

When I give the message box in this format, the message box does not remains in the taskbar
 but the variable "Result" always returns "No".

Thanks in Advance

Comment: in which class/thread are you putting above code?

Comment: I have a created a class in business layer as  'public class WordTemplate' and included the code in it. what do you mean by "which class"?

Comment: I'm not very sure, if the MessageBox not showed from the UI thread, it may not be on top of the main Form. check [so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576156/winforms-how-can-i-make-messagebox-appear-centered-on-mainform)

Comment: The form has only loading panel(progress bar). After opening a document, the form hides behind the document. After the close button in the document is clicked, i have code for showing the message box whether to save it in repository or not.

Comment: any one answer for my question

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
DialogResult Secondpopups = MessageBox.Show(new Form() { TopMost = true },"Message u need to diaplay", "Title of the Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```